Remove all duplicate rows except first and last in pandas
I have a signal log with a lot of redundant data that I parse with pandas. To remove all duplicate rows besides first and last I use following code:
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "B": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
    }
)
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  0
2  3  0
3  4  0
4  5  1
5  6  1
6  7  1
7  8  2
8  9  3
>>> df = df[~((df.B == df.B.shift()) & (df.B == df.B.shift(-1)))]
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  0
3  4  0
4  5  1
6  7  1
7  8  2
8  9  3

The log files can get pretty big, hundreds of megabytes and the app is running on AWS EC2 VPS with only 1 Gb of RAM. So if I try to parse a large file it crashes the server. So my questions are these:

Does this method require 3 times the size of the file of RAM (because it "creates" 3 dataframes)?
Is there a more memory efficient way to do it?


you can use the polars module instead of pandas

Which line does your program crash on?

@Dogbert it doesn't crash my laptop, only ec2, so I can't tell exactly when it happens.

Are the logs being read from a file? Pandas has features for reading only portions of a file into memory.

@Viktor try adding print(df) after the line that reads the dataframe. It might be crashing while reading the dataframe.

@iBeMeltin I want to compare pandas and polars on this task. Do you know what's the polars way of doing what @mozway suggested m = df['B'].diff().ne(0)  m |= df['B'].diff(-1).ne(0)?

updated: ```m = df.select(
(pl.col("B").diff().fill_null(1).ne(0)) | (pl.col("B").diff(-1).fill_null(1).ne(0))
).to_series()
out = df.filter(m)```

You could try to break the logic in successive parts to avoid having everything at once in memory. I would also avoid the ~ operation and compute directly the inverse with != and boolean OR (using De Morgan's law):
m = df['B'] != df['B'].shift()
m |= df['B'] != df['B'].shift(-1)

out = df[m]

You could also try of diff is more memory efficient than shift:
m = df['B'].diff().ne(0)
m |= df['B'].diff(-1).ne(0)

out = df[m]

Output:
   A  B
0  1  0
3  4  0
4  5  1
6  7  1
7  8  2
8  9  3


import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "B": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
    }
)

df['m1'] = m1 = (df.B != df.B.shift())
df['m2'] = m2 = (df.B != df.B.shift(-1))
mask = (m1 | m2)
df_filtered = df[mask]

print(df_filtered)
'''
   A  B     m1     m2
0  1  0   True  False
3  4  0  False   True
4  5  1   True  False
6  7  1  False   True
7  8  2   True   True
8  9  3   True   True

'''

